# Arithmetic overflow nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CHARG] [nchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [MATNR] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [VLTYP] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [VLPLA] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [NLTYP] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [NLPLA] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [BDATU] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [DATES] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [TIMES] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

and I use this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [ID], [CHARG], [MATNR], [VLTYP], [VLPLA],
         [NLTYP], [NLPLA], [BDATU], [DATES], 
         [TIMES], [TIMESTAMP],
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NLPLA ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS lastN,
         CASE WHEN NLPLA ='X-X-1' THEN (CAST(NLPLA as nchar(6))+'-'+(CAST(RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NLPLA ORDER BY TIMESTAMP desc )as nchar(3))))
            ELSE (CAST(NLPLA as nchar(6))+'-'+(CAST(RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NLPLA ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC)as nchar(3)))) End as LINESKATE,
         CASE  WHEN NLPLA = 'X-X-1' THEN 'X-X-1'
        WHEN MATNR <> FIRST_VALUE(MATNR) OVER (PARTITION BY NLPLA ORDER BY timestamp) AND NLPLA !='X-X-1'
            THEN 'WRONG'
        WHEN NLPLA LIKE 'DIFF%' THEN 'Different'
        WHEN TIMESTAMP = LAST_VALUE(TIMESTAMP) over (partition by MATNR order by timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AND NLPLA !='X-X-1'
             THEN 'LAST'
        ELSE 'RIGHT' 
        END as status_text
     FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
)t
WHERE (NLPLA = 'X-X-1' AND lastN <= 6) OR (NLPLA !='X-X-1')
```

And it happens to me that I sometimes get an error message:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

Is there something wrong with, for example, in the table design that caused this or somehow modified the SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give enough length for `NCHAR` in the below conversion. I think the rank is going beyond 999.

```sql
 (CAST(NLPLA as nchar(6))+'-'+(CAST(RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NLPLA ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC)as nchar(3)))) End as LINESKATE, -- you have defined NCHAR(3) here
```